# error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Image.sprite' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm facing a problem right now.The console shows:

> Assets\Scripts\ScreenshotPhoto.cs(34,38): error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'Image.sprite' cannot be used like a method.

Code:

```
void getPicAndShow()
{

    string pathToFile = files[shownScreenshotIndex];
    Texture2D texture = getScreenshotImage(pathToFile);
    Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height),
        new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    canvas.GetComponent<Image>().sprite() = sp;

}
```

Comment: canvas.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sp;

Comment: Yes simply remove these `()` after `.sprite` ...